# Probabilistic model to approximate price of stock

Tags: probability

We use the simplistic probabilistic model for the price $S_n$ of a stock in $n$ days from now. Then for large n we have approximately
$$S_n = S_0 + a_nN$$
where $S_0$ is the current stock price and $N$ is a standard normal random variable. Express $a_n$ in terms of $σ$ and $n$.

Is my solution correct?

$$Var(S_n)=Var(S_0+a_nN)$$
$$Var(S_n)=Var(S_0)+Var(a_nN)$$
$$Var(S_0)=0 $$ since $S_0$ is the stock price and it is a constant.

Therefore we have,

$$Var(S_n)=a_n^2Var(N)$$

Now, since $N$ ~ $(0,1)$ then $Var(N)=1$ and so we have

$$Var(S_n)=a_n^2$$

If we square root both sides to find $\sigma$ we will obtain

$$\sigma=\sqrt {Var(S_n)}=\sqrt {a_n^2}$$

Therefore,

$$\sigma=a_n$$